# How to get data from google sheets as an array of dictionary

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-apps-script

I'm having difficulty formatting the data contained in rows and columns as an array of dictionaries. Below is the format I'm trying to achieve:

```swift
[[id: "abchdha", name: "Orange", health: "fruit", price: 50], 
[id: "123fsf", name: "Apple", health: "fruit", price: 50]]
```

Here is my google sheets script:

```
var secret = "mysecretcode"

function getFirebaseUrl(jsonPath) {
  /*
  We then make a URL builder
  This takes in a path, and
  returns a URL that updates the data in that path
  */
  return (
    'myfirebaselink' +
    jsonPath +
    '.json?auth=' +
    secret
  )
}

function syncMasterSheet(excelData) {
  /*
  We make a PUT (update) request,
  and send a JSON payload
  More info on the REST API here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start
  */
  var options = {
    method: 'put',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(excelData)
  }
  var fireBaseUrl = getFirebaseUrl('masterSheet')

  /*
  We use the UrlFetchApp google scripts module
  More info on this here : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app
  */
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(fireBaseUrl, options)
}

function startSync() {
  //Get the currently active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  //Get the number of rows and columns which contain some content
  var [rows, columns] = [sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()]
  //Get the data contained in those rows and columns as a 2 dimensional array
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows, columns).getValues()

  syncMasterSheet(data)
}
```

I need the function `startSync()` to set `var data` equal to my intended format. :)

Comment: In order to correctly understand about the value of `data` of `var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows, columns).getValues()`, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Sorry! I put a comment earlier but I guess it didn't post. [Here](https://i.imgur.com/iHnOFUv.png) it is. Also [here](https://imgur.com/sJbfAfD) is my Firebase database. The top branch under node food is what I want my data to look like, and the bottom is the current output.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. But unfortunately, I couldn't understand about the relationship between your image and the value of `[[id: "abchdha", name: "Orange", health: "fruit", price: 50], [id: "123fsf", name: "Apple", health: "fruit", price: 50]]`.

Comment: @Tanaike I edited the prior comment with a firebase snapshot if that helps? [here](https://imgur.com/sJbfAfD)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I might have commented while you editing your comment. I apologize for this. In your situation, the Spreadsheet has the column "A" to "D", and for `[id: "abchdha", name: "Orange", health: "fruit", price: 50]`, the column "A", "B", "C" and "D" are `name`, `health`, `price` and undefined, respectively. If my understanding is correct, where is `id`? By the way, `[id: "abchdha", name: "Orange", health: "fruit", price: 50]` is not an object. Can you provide the input and output you want by adding the text data to your question?

Comment: Hopefully, I can explain this well. Each row in [this](https://imgur.com/mZHhY34) spreadsheet has 4 data points (name, health, price and url), ignore ID for now.  When I sync to firebase, in my swift app I use each data point to instantiate a product object. Using the script above with the same spreadsheet I get [this](https://imgur.com/A8BhDPY) in firebase. My goal is to use the above spreadsheet to achieve [this dictionary](https://imgur.com/b4O6QLQ) output in firebase instead.

Comment: From my understanding, I would make an array of dictionaries using each column header as a key and each value in the same row as dictionary. Giving the output `[ [id: "abchdha", name: "Orange", health: "fruit", price: 50], [id: "123fsf", name: "Apple", health: "fruit", price: 50] ]`

Comment: Thank you for adding the information. At your replying, `4 data points (name, health, price and url)` is used. But your `Giving the output [ [id: "abchdha", name: "Orange", health: "fruit", price: 50], [id: "123fsf", name: "Apple", health: "fruit", price: 50] ]` doesn't use `url`. So I cannot still understand about the value and your goal. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. When I could correctly understand your question, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize for this situation.

Comment: Ah sorry, it is my mistake - I was making up data and rushed through it. Please ignore the `Id` and use `url` instead. The desired output is `[[name: "Apple", health: "fruit", price: 50, "urlexample.com"], [name: "Orange", health: "fruit", price: 50, url: "urlexample.com"]]`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I cannot understand `[[name: "Apple", health: "fruit", price: 50, "urlexample.com"],]`. Is that `[{name: "Apple", health: "fruit", price: 50, "urlexample.com"},]` or `[[{name: "Apple", health: "fruit", price: 50, "urlexample.com"}],]`? By the way, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? I would like to think of the sample script. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: I think it would be `[{name: "Apple", health: "fruit", price: 50, "urlexample.com"},]`. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A4NbVftOxWz3SI4fIoMZqSXg7BMiOYfmj_KAgqGWnDk/edit?usp=sharing) is the sample spreadsheet. Use script editor under help.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about the result object. But, unfortunately, I couldn't open your shared Spreadsheet.

Comment: [Try this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A4NbVftOxWz3SI4fIoMZqSXg7BMiOYfmj_KAgqGWnDk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could open your shared Spreadsheet. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Yes! Exactly what I wanted. Thank you loads! :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You want to convert the values of Spreadsheet to `[{name: "Apple", health: "fruit", price: 50, url: "example.com"},,,]`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please modify the function of `startSync()` as follows.

```
function startSync() {
  //Get the currently active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //Get the number of rows and columns which contain some content
  var [rows, columns] = [sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()];
  //Get the data contained in those rows and columns as a 2 dimensional array
  var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows, columns).getValues();

  // I modified below script.
  var header = data[0];
  data.shift();
  var convertedData = data.map(function(row) {
    return header.reduce(function(o, h, i) {
      o[h] = row[i];
      return o;
    }, {});
  });

  syncMasterSheet(convertedData);
}
```

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)